# Time Travel and Virtual Particles correlation?

Tags: time, quantum-interpretations

Virtual Particles in Quantum Physics are particles that can form in any place, including a vacuum, and are created in a pair of particles opposite each other, and are usually eliminated. When these particles are formed on the horizon of a Black Hole, Hawking radiation occurs, when one particle falls into the black hole, while the other escapes. The particles are supposed to have 0 energy, and since one exists and continues to affect things around it, the black hole must lose energy.

My explanation with reverse time travel for this is that the particle that now exists is a particle that previously in the black hole, and escaped through reverse time travel.

To begin, first visualize a road that curves as below:

=========>V.
....................V
V<========<
V....................
.>=========>.

(Equal signs and "Arrows" represent roads, .s are placeholders)

If your point of view cuts through the middle of the road, than there is three roads, and in your point of view, there is indeed 3 roads, and no way to disprove it. If your point of view moves along the right, two road merge into each other and disappear, while one continues.

Basically, imagine the first the first two roads happening within the black hole, and you moving to the right with a vertical line as moving through time with one slice of space. "Virtual particles" appear at the second turn in the road, and at the first turn, the mass inside the black hole and one of the virtual particles eliminate each other, while the other virtual particle escapes.

To a person which looks at the whole road, it's a single road bending back and back around on itself. Likewise, to a fourth dimensional being (with time being the fourth dimension), they can see that it's only a single particle going back through and around time to escape the "inescapable" gravity of the black hole.

P.S. 
Self eliminating pairs of virtual particles would just be circles in time-space.

P.P.S.
Since virtual particles are in antimatter and matter pairs, perhaps particles travelling back through time have reversed gravity and reversed charge?

So basically, the question is "Is this possible?" and "If so, why would this happen?" , and "Does it have any Implications?

(Tell me if this should go on Physics instead, I was thinking that this was a bit too Sci-fi-ish)

Comment: Can you vague that up for me a bit?  But seriously, there's a lot here that really does not contact gravity theory or quantum field their very well at all. For example, your description of Hawking radiation is quite vague. And your explanation of virtual particles as "just circles in time-space" is also. Please keep in mind that not only have I measured it, I've demonstrated the experiment  as a lab instructor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift

Comment: Have you looked at the Wheeler-Feynman 'absorber theory of time'? The idea would be that particles happily whizz backwards and forwards in time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feynman diagrams suggest this kind of thing, where they can be turned around the time axis and viewed as for instance particles going forward, or an equuvalentvparticle going backwards. It is well accepted that an electron is 'equivalent' to a positron going back in time, in quantum field theory. But given that time is not really at all integrated into QFT it's not clear what that would mean if it is truly the case. See tge duscussion here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/is-anti-matter-matter-going-backwards-in-time

You have to look at the no cloning theorem and closed time-like curves and so on to see some of the issues and limits.

The most radical thought exoeriment, was Archibal Wheeler's https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe Note that the electron/positron is soecial though, it has no internal structure demonstrated to some very high number of decimal places. Other particle types and interactions get rapidly more complex.

Your black hole example is really just a distraction, from the wider issue of virtual particles/antiparticles and time and what they mean. And the core of that is, our intuitions are not good, and the universe is exactly as weird as it wishes to be, not as we wish. https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/quantum-weirdness
What is really interesting about blackholes is how information is preserved, and their holographic boundaries.